# How to call JS .apply() method

Tags: javascript

Despite all books and blogs I've consulted on this , I have not fully understood how to call js .apply() which is famed to be so important in changing function context. Sometimes I get it right, sometimes I don't,sign all is not well yet.

```
function sumArr(arr){
var sum =0;
for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
sum+= arr[i];
}
return sum
}
 var x = [3, 6, 8];
var obj ={
name: 'somebody',
scores:[3, 6, 8]
}
// console.log(sumArr(x)) outputs 17, fine!
// Now sumArr.apply(null, x) outputs 0
// Next, sumArr.apply(obj, obj.scores) outputs 0 
please could somebody tell me how to call this method correctly.
```

Comment: Using `.apply()` doesn't make sense for the examples shown, because `sumArr()` expects a single argument that is an array. Just use `sumArr(obj.scores)`. Or use `.call()` instead of `.apply()`: `sumArr.call(null, x)`.

Comment: "famed to be so important" - less so now that we have the spread syntax (`...arr`) in ES6.

Comment: By "*changing function context*" I guess you mean *setting a function's this*. Typically you'd only use *apply* or *call* if you want to set *this* for the called function. You aren't doing that, nor does the called function use *this*, so what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.apply()` takes elements out of array passed in second parameter and passes them as parameter to the function, so in your examples when `.apply(null, [3,6,8])` actually calls the method as in `sumArr(3,6,8)`. So the correct way to pass the parameters would be like `sumArr.apply(null, [[3,6,8]]`. So your code snippet would look like

```
function sumArr(arr){
    var sum =0;
    for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
        sum+= arr[i];
    }
    return sum
}
var x = [3, 6, 8];
var obj ={
    name: 'somebody',
    scores:[3, 6, 8]
}
console.log(sumArr(x));
//.apply() takes each array elment and passes it as a parameter
console.log(sumArr.apply(null, [x]));
console.log(sumArr.apply(obj, [obj.scores]));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you wrap the array inside an array just so you could use `apply()` instead of `call`?

Comment: I completely agree, `.call()` would be more suitable here, but in the answer I wanted to demonstrate how `.apply()` works.

Answer (score 3):

The `.apply()` method is for passing in an array to a function *as individual arguments*, so `sumArr.apply(null, x)` here is essentially equivalent to `sumArr(3, 6, 8)`.

The value `3` doesn't have a length property, so your loop never begins.

If you want to pass parameters as themselves, you can use `.call()`, but it's not clear what you're trying to do here.

```js
function sumArr(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum
}

var x = [3, 6, 8];
var obj = {
  name: 'somebody',
  scores: [3, 6, 8]
}

console.log(sumArr.call(null, x));
console.log(sumArr.call(null, obj.scores));
```